# How to install a program under Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, installation

I got a new Windows 8.1 PC and downloaded an .exe from the web. 
After doubleclicking the .exe for installation, I only get a window shown that reads "Open file with...".
I turned off the "SmartScreen filter" already but I still can't install the .exe.
How to install a .exe under Windows 8.1?

Comment: *.exe* files in Windows 8.1 should be opened such as in any other Windows OS. Are you sure it's an exe file? Windows have, by default, set to hide file extension, so this file could have some other extension and not .exe. E.g. somefile.exe.txt showed as somefile.exe, because .txt is extension and it is hidden, except if you have hiding extension disabled.

Comment: Really should check the file with some type of virus/malware scanner before trying to run it too, since it's unclear how "computer savvy" you are, there are lots of "bad" exe's on "the web"

Comment: Is this just  1 exe you can't install,  if so I think the file is corrupted

Answer (score 1):

Confirm the file is a .EXE file. Go to desktop and in your Explorer window locate the file, set the view to Details in  the View Ribbon, and whilst there tick the "File name extensions" so you can see exactly what you are trying to execute.

If need be check the properties of the file for more information.

Comment: And if it is a legit .EXE, what then? This doesn't actually answer the question :(